# ZF2 + Doctrine 2 & access to zf config

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a doctrine entity that holds a reference to a file. When the entity is deleted, the referenced file should also be removed using @HasLifecycleCallbacks and preRemove(). The problem is, that the reference to the file saved in the entity is a relative path and the first part to complete it, is saved in the zf2 config.

How can I access the zf2 config from within the entity, so that I can build a complete path and delete the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to inject anything you wish into entity by attach event listener.

Your main `Module.php` file:

```
namespace Application

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap (MvcEvent $e)
    {
        /*
         * inject service manager into entities on postload event
         */
        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $doctrineEventManager = $serviceManager
            ->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default')
            ->getEventManager();
        $doctrineEventManager->addEventListener(
            array(\Doctrine\ORM\Events::postLoad),
            new \Application\Entity\InjectListener($serviceManager)
        );
    {
}
```

`Application\Entity\InjectListener` class:

```
namespace Application\Entity;

class InjectListener
{
    private $sm;

    public function __construct($sm)
    {
        $this->sm = $sm;
    }

    public function postload($eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        $entity->setServiceManager($this->sm);
    }
}
```

All your entities must extends class with method `setServiceManager`. After that application config inside entity:

```
$config = $this->sm->get('Configuration');
```

If you don't need to inject all service manager, but just config, instead of `setServiceManager` method make `setApplicationConfig` method:

```
namespace Application\Entity;

class InjectListener
{
    private $config;

    public function __construct($sm)
    {
        $this->sm = $sm;
    }

    public function postload($eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        $entity->setApplicationConfig(
            $this->sm->get('Configuration')
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: To update this answer a little bit, if you don't want to update all your entities you should create an interface and implement in those entities that need it. So something like `ServiceManagerAwareInterface` and then you can easily check in your `InjectListener::postLoad()` whether the Entity is an instanceof `ServiceManagerAwareInterface`, if so you can set the manager.